# Best way to implement the extract and assign operators for S3 class

Tags: r

Say I have a list-like object of `foo` class and I want to implement the assign operator for it. The class differs from normal lists in having each element named with a `"bar_"` prefix (this is just a made-up example). So my naive implementation of assign operator would be:

```
"[<-.foo" <- function(x, i, value) {
   x[paste0("bar_", i)] <- value
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work since it goes into infinite loop:

```
as.foo <- function(x) {
  names(x) <- paste0("bar_", names(x))
  class(x) <- c(class(x), "foo")
  x
}

x <- as.foo(list(a = 1, b = 2))
x["a"] <- 42
## Error: C stack usage  7970836 is too close to the limit
```

What would be the best practice in implementing such method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subset/subassign functions are special, because there is no generic and no default method at the R level. That is all handled in C code. The reason is of course performance: S3 method dispatch is relatively slow and subsetting needs to be as fast as possible because it is used so much.

I would remove the class temporarily:

```
"[<-.foo" <- function(x, i, value) {
  theclass <- class(x)
  class(x) <- class(x)[-inherits(x, "foo", TRUE)]
  x[paste0("bar_", i)] <- value
  class(x) <- theclass
  x
}
```

Btw., I would rewrite `as.foo`:

```
as.foo <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(is.list(x))
  names(x) <- paste0("bar_", names(x))
  class(x) <- c("foo", attr(x, "class"))
  x
}
```

This avoids adding implicit classes to the class attribute.

Comment: This is what would I do, but it seems very ugly, isn't there really anything better than this?!

Comment: With most functions, you would simply call the default method. However, there is no default method for `[<-`.

Comment: Welcome again in R inferno :)